# How to do I add Scanner inputs into array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program where the user will enter strings of sentences (one line each) and I have to add it to two String arrays of 10 cells each.

For example (user input):

```
line1
line2

line3
line4
```

Line1 and line2 will be appended to first array. Line2 and line2, after recognizing the blank line, will be to be appended to second array. Each line is a new cell.

```
String[] firstArray = new String[10];
String[] secondArray = new String[10];
```

I am stuck on taking this user input and successfully adding it to the arrays. I keep getting weird results where the Scanner keeps going for 10 or 11 times and does not stop after the second set of input.

My code so far is below, I have yet to create second array and figure out what to do after a blank line:

```
public static void stringStream(Scanner sc) {
    String[] firstArray = new String[10];
    boolean streamEnded = false;
    int index = 0;
    while (!streamEnded && sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String sentence = sc.nextLine();
        if (sentence.length() == 0) {
            streamEnded = true;
        } else {
            firstArray[index] = sc.nextLine();
            index++;
    for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length-1; i++) {
        String words = firstArray[i];
        if(words != null) {
            System.out.println(words);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: I was trying to say "String" I probably made a typo. I have my code so far posted above, main confusion is when user enters a second set of strings and putting them into the a second array. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Scanner(System.in)

```
import java.util.*;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
     firstArray[i] = in.nextLine();
}
```

and you can do the same thing for the second array